# How to use a fast way for oracle sql to find the last log column in Jobs run log

Tags: sql, oracle

The run log have too much data that i can't search it in fast ways.Now i only want to get the last log data in this log table in oracle jobs. Pls give me help.Best!

Comment: Can you add more information. It's very vague from your question

Comment: the data set is random and if use linear search it will cost about 24-26 min to select one for about 65179620 links data ,is it any method to avoid linear search use only index to let to speed up?!Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are various options to return a sinlge row but these will do it with only a single table scan:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ( SELECT *
         FROM   log_table
         ORDER BY entry_date DESC
       )
WHERE  ROWNUM = 1;
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM   ( SELECT l.*,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY entry_date DESC ) rn
         FROM   log_table l
       )
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

or (for Oracle 12)

```
SELECT *
FROM   log_table
ORDER BY entry_date DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use max(date) like this

```
select * from log where date=(select max(date) from log)
```

It'll use indexes (if they exists)

If you have no date field you can use, and this can be even better:

```
select * from log where rowid=(select max(rowid) from log)
```

Comment: This will return multiple rows if there are entries tied for the latest date.

Comment: @MT0 May be. It aso can be, that topic starter doesn't have column date at all. But if he can use this method for PK or rowid, and it'll be best )

Comment: Why will it be the best? It will do 2 table scans (one to find the `MAX()` and another to return one-or-more matching rows). Also - ordering by `ROWID` pseudocolumn does not guarantee that entries will be in entry order (or that entry order matches the log date order). The same is true for a primary key backed by a sequence created with `NOORDER` on a distributed system.